# Regex findall command want to specify in most common name algorithm - Python 3

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to make a python program that searches an imported text file for occurances of common words (names in this case) and then prints a list of the top three most common names in the file. Some names repeat due to the count of names then being higher or lower (less or more popular). The text file is simply a collections of names with either a F or M on the same line to distinguish it as a male or female name. I have the code

```
N=3
words = re.findall (r'\w+', data)
top_words_all = Counter(words).most_common(N)
for word, frequency in top_words_all:
print("%s - %d" % (word, frequency))
```

(Note: 'data' is the reading of the text file.) It gives me a nice list of three words that occur the most but the trouble is that the first and second most common on the count is F and M because it counts it as a separate word. How do I count each word along with their F or M a few spaces away. To give you an idea of what the text file looks like:

```
Drew  M
Drew  M
Drew  M
Drew  M
Steven  M
Steven  M
Sally  F
Sally  F
```

Not only that, but this code is just to print out a top three list for all names (male or female). I would like to do two more which would do the most common male names and female names. I am guessing that when you include the M/F in the word then I could just find the words with the occurance of "M" or "F" and then display them only. Please help. I am new to coding as you can tell and need some desperate assistance. Please explain your chosen coding to me if at all possible so that I understand what the code or functions actually do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\w+\s+(?:M|F)` regular expression. It checks for more than one space with the following `M` or `F` character. `?:` is a [non-capturing group](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#non-capturing-and-named-groups).

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> data = """
... Drew  M
... Drew  F
... Drew  F
... Drew  M
... Steven  M
... Steven  F
... Sally  F
... Sally  M
... """
>>> words = re.findall (r'\w+\s+(?:M|F)?', data)
>>> top_words_all = Counter(words).most_common(3)
>>> for word, frequency in top_words_all:
...     print("%s - %d" % (word, frequency))
... 
Drew  M - 2
Drew  F - 2
Steven  F - 1
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you so much! Do you know any way though to only include female or male names in a search so that i get top three female names and top three male names instead...

Comment: I was just playing around with the code to get it to do male and female names as i asked and just removed the 'M|' from the code and it does work, though if it is '(?:F)' then if there is a male name starting with F then it counts it. How do I end the match of the word at the F or M and not allow it to continue on the next line?

Comment: @user3451030 this regexp `(\w+\s+(?:F))+?` just worked for me , give it a try.